# How to index bulk parent child document using Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I want to bulk index parent and child document in the same index in elasticsearch.
I am using elasticsearch version 6.1.1 and nest version 6.0. 
Here is the code I am using.

For Parent

```
  var result = elasticService.Bulk(b => b.IndexMany<Item>(lstItems,  
    (bulkDes, record) => bulkDes.Index(Constants.INDEX_NAME)
                .Document(record)));
```

For Child

```
    var indexResponse = elasticService.Bulk(s => s.IndexMany<ItemFacInv> 
    (itemFacInvs,(bulkDescriptor, record) =>
      bulkDescriptor.Index(Constants.INDEX_NAME)
             .Id(record.item_fac_inv_pk)
        .Routing(new Routing(record.item_pk.ToString()))
          .Document(record)));
```

Here I am getting an error:- The index doesn't contain 2 type.

Comment: Take a look at the Parent/Child documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/6.x/parent-child-relationships.html

Comment: Please can you post a succinct, but complete example of what you have tried, where you are getting an error, and what the error is.

Comment: @RussCam Thanks the above link work for me. Actually, I was missing a single thing. Thanks again

Comment: it might be worth adding an answer with how you resolved the problem so that others in future who may get stuck in the same way can see how you solved it